# Regular Expressions in R - Sort Data Frame

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following data frame.
I have a list with the most frequent words (table "imp") and below I have a table with the different models.
What I have to do is to create a second column (name "words") with the most frequent words sorted decreasingly (such as it shows below).

```
imp<-data.frame(word=c("ls","lxl","mec","hatch","bi"),frec=c(100,90,80,85,70)) 

  word   frec
   ls     100
   lxl    90
   mec    80
   hatch  85
   bi     70

table=data.frame(code=c(1,2,3,4,5),model=c("hatch ls 1.0 8v", " onix 2016 ls 1.0 ar condicionado + direcao hidraulica","onix hatch ls 1.0 8v flexpower 5p mec.",
                                       "volvo xc bi turbo blindada","honda civic sedan lxl 1.8 flex 16v mec 4p aceita troca"),
                                       words=c("ls hatch", "ls","ls hatch","bi","lxl"))

code                                        model               words
  1                                        hatch ls 1.0 8v   ls hatch
  2  onix 2016 ls 1.0 ar condicionado + direcao hidraulica       ls
  3                 onix hatch ls 1.0 8v flexpower 5p mec.   ls hatch
  4                             volvo xc bi turbo blindada       bi
  5 honda civic sedan lxl 1.8 flex 16v mec 4p aceita troca   lxl mec
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `lxl mec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(table$model, paste(imp$word, collapse="|")), 
      function(x) paste(head(x[order(-imp$frec[match(x, imp$word)])], 2), collapse= " "))
```

Comment: Perfect! That is what I was looking for

Comment: Thats ok, but in some cases the function does not work ok for an exact match. For example, str_extract_all("make thingsdo happn", "make|thin|happn|link|space") will return 

    [1] "make"  "thin"  "happn"     , and "thin" is not good

Comment: @lolo You meant `space` is not returned?  Try creating word boundary i.e `paste0("\\b(", paste(imp$word, collapse="|"), ")\\b")`